# Strange result when entering squared bracket close on German Mac

Tags: macos, keyboard

I do programming with two different Macs, both with an original Apple keyboard and using the German keyboard layout.

There is a strange issue, occurring from time to time. If I enter the squared bracket close ("]"), some other, invisible characters are inserted as well, and e.g. the Python parser does not work on the provided code.

Consider the following two lines of Python code:

```
def test(self, target, name):
    target[name] = self
```

and the resulting binary output

```
$ cat issue.py|xxd
0000000: 6465 6620 7465 7374 2873 656c 662c 2074  def test(self, t
0000010: 6172 6765 742c 206e 616d 6529 3a0a 2020  arget, name):.
0000020: 2020 7461 7267 6574 5b6e 616d 655d c2a0    target[name]..
0000030: 3d20 7365 6c66 0a                        = self.
```

The string "*] =*" should be ASCII 0x5D 0x20 0x3D, but instead of a space (0x20), the bytes 0xC2 0xA0 are inserted.

Do you have any idea what the problem might be, and how it could be solved? I have not tampered the OS X keyboard layout in any way, and it does not happen all the time, only about twice a day - but always when typing that special character, "]".

[Edit]

In order to type the "]" character, I need to press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd>, so only 1 meta key is involved. If I hit the wrong one, I would not have produced the right character. Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> on its own does not produce a character at all, and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>space</kbd> switches windows, which I would have noticed. So why is no regular *space* inserted?

Comment: Does it happen on both Macs?

Comment: @patrix yes, and it already happened when OS X was still named like cats..

Comment: Fat fingers maybe? I have the same "problem" with the Swiss keyboard sometimes, when I'm too slow with the meta keys (or don't hit the key correctly).

Comment: @patrix I don't know, maybe, I'm a fast typer and may not always be as accurate as I need to be with the meta keys, however I don't know how this could explain the actual behavior. Please see my edit above.

Comment: c2 a0 is the utf-8 no break space, normally input via option plus space.